# Help with setting static ip

Tags: pi-2, static-ip, raspbian-buster

/etc/Interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.205.159
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

So i want to know if im doing something wrong as this interfaces configuration makes dhcpcd.service exit (most likely cause it configures a static ip but if thats the case why dosent it configure it correctly) doing `hostname -I` gives me an empty line, theres nothing in routes and `ifconfig` shows only lo running

Comment: Raspbian version?

Comment: Is there any reason you ignored the warning in `/etc/network/interfaces`?
**# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'**
If you really must use static IP do it properly see [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) In addition the values you are attempting to use are inconsistent. There is little reason to set a static IP (particularly if you don't understand networking)

Comment: Do you tried to set a static ip address in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on a fresh flashed Raspbian Buster installation?

Answer (score 1):

The network manager of Buster is working (by default) with `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Therefore, change the configuration that file as you want.

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Change these lines as you want:

```
# static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.205.159/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.205.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.251 

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Then, recover the `/etc/network/interfaces` by adding these lines:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Also, you have configured the `/etc/network/interfaces` in the wrong way. If you're going to set the IP address on `192.168.205.159` with `255.255.255.0` subnet, you can't set a gateway with `192.168.0.1` address if you are using a simple local network. The gateway **should be** something `192.168.205.x`.

Comment: @Meow Have you restart network service or rebooted the rpi?

Comment: @Meow The same situation with `cat /etc/hostname`?

Comment: @Meow Also, you should recover the /etc/network/interfaces and add interface eth0 manual there. || Answer updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103877/discussion-between-meow-and-m-rostami).

Comment: @M.Rostami the etc/network/interfaces you listed is obsolete - I suggest you look at an unmodified Buster installation.

Comment: @Milliways I've edited that part. As you know, in this case, `iface eth0 inet manual` should be added. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Deleted all the useless comments, but im still having a problem with not seeing any ip come up in hostname -I (i have a question can i set this up to work with any router in a network cause from what i see i need the ip of the router)

Comment: @Meow Please add the output of this command: `cat /etc/hosts`. It should have something like:  `127.0.1.1       raspberrypi`

Comment: @Meow If you are looking for a command to gives you the exact IP address of the `eth0` for using on bash, etc, you can fire this command: `ip -4 addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'`

Comment: @M.Rostami "As you know, in this case, iface eth0 inet manual should be added" I know no such thing. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for Stretch/Buster defaults - in fact these effectively do NOTHING, and the file can just be deleted. All "manual" means is that the interface is configured by some other process.

Comment: @Milliways I have read something on a SE answer here that talked about it. By the way, thank you for your clarification.